I have a problem with Gsheet API, Render and Flask, what can I do?
I'm trying to put a dynamic page on a website that is being hosted on Render.
I have a scraper that records data on a google sheet. The scraper gets the data, throws on that sheet and save the data on two html tables, that should appear on a page of the website.
That's working fine on VSCode. But on render, for some reason, I get an error message when it tries to acess the google sheets API.
The Github is public, right here: https://github.com/guiqueiroz27/caneta_render
The app.py page is like that:
import os
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from flask import Flask, render_template
from raspador import atualizar_planilha


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/infos")
def infos():
    return render_template('infos.html')

@app.route("/projetos")
def projetos():
    return render_template('projetos.html')

@app.route("/publicacoes")
def publicacoes():
    return render_template('publicacoes.html')

@app.route("/leissp")
def leissp():
    # Chamando a função atualizar_planilha() para obter o HTML das tabelas
    tabela1_html, tabela2_html = atualizar_planilha()


    # Passando o HTML das tabelas para o template leissp.html
    return render_template('leissp.html', tabela1_html=tabela1_html, tabela2_html=tabela2_html)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

The scraping file, raspador, it is like that in the final part that records on google sheets:
def atualizar_planilha(data_inicio='01/01/2024', planilha_key='gsheet_key', arquivo_credenciais="insperaa-f16b8130bed9.json"):
    # Obtenha a data atual
    data_fim = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    # Obtenha os DataFrames das leis sancionadas
    tabela_leis_prefeitura_sp = leis_prefeitura_sp(data_inicio, data_fim)
    tabela_leis_governo_sp = leis_governo_sp(data_inicio, data_fim)

    # Carregue as credenciais do Google Sheets
    conta = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(arquivo_credenciais)
    api = gspread.authorize(conta)

    # Abra a planilha e as abas relevantes
    planilha = api.open_by_key(planilha_key)
    sheet_municipal = planilha.worksheet("municipal")
    sheet_estadual = planilha.worksheet("estadual")

    # Obtenha os dados atuais da planilha
    dados_municipais = sheet_municipal.get_all_values()
    dados_estaduais = sheet_estadual.get_all_values()

    # Converta os dados em DataFrames
    df_municipal = pd.DataFrame(dados_municipais[1:], columns=dados_municipais[0])
    df_estadual = pd.DataFrame(dados_estaduais[1:], columns=dados_estaduais[0])

    # Adicione novos dados aos DataFrames
    df_municipal = pd.concat([df_municipal, tabela_leis_prefeitura_sp], ignore_index=True)
    df_estadual = pd.concat([df_estadual, tabela_leis_governo_sp], ignore_index=True)

    # Transformar os DataFrames em tabelas HTML
    tabela_html_municipal = df_municipal.to_html(index=False)
    tabela_html_estadual = df_estadual.to_html(index=False)

    # Atualizar a planilha com os novos dados
    sheet_municipal.update([df_municipal.columns.values.tolist()] + df_municipal.values.tolist())
    sheet_estadual.update([df_estadual.columns.values.tolist()] + df_estadual.values.tolist())

    # Retorne as tabelas HTML
    return tabela_html_municipal, tabela_html_estadual

Thats the error that appears on the log of Render.
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound: <Response [404]>

I generated a new API key, but it didnt solve
